# Security of using a browser session within a webpage iframe

Tags: php, security, web

As the title says, I intend to create a web-app that uses an iframe to lock all my web sessions within the server itself. Thus when accessing from a client, i can still visit other sites, while being in the main browser page.

Since the website itself is making the connection through the page, for security wise, am I technically going through a VPN since the connection goes like

Client -> Server Hosting the Main Webpage -> facebook.com

Will my connection to facebook.com come from the client, or the server?
And is this type of solution even feasible?

Comment: What your are trying to do not going to work for non-trivial sites (at least without non-trivial effort), but in proxying requests through your own server is valid and proven approach for basic sites/requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will my connection to facebook.com come from the client, or the
>   server? And is this type of solution even feasible?

If you're *just* using an IFrame, then the request will come from the browser.

If you've made a proxy handler on your site which makes a back-end HTTP request, then it will come from the server. E.g. the handler could take a query string parameter like `url` - `http://example.com?url=https://facebook.com`.

Three relevant security issues spring to mind with this approach.

1. [Server-side Request Forgery](http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/server-side-request-forgery-vulnerability/) - ensuring an attacker cannot browse to things in your DMZ like `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://192.168.2.4`.
2. [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) - lots of sites use this header, or the new [CSP2 `frame-ancestors`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-ancestors) header to prevent themselves from being framed. You could though strip out such headers in your proxy code.
3. Browser trust. If I'm on your website at `http://example.com` (or even `https://example.com`), how do I know I'm logging into Facebook. There is no assurance other than the fact the IFramed page *looks* like Facebook. Any case, if you're proxying the request to Facebook, how do I know you're not capturing my credentials?

If this is just for yourself, then you can ignore points one and three somewhat, however you have no way of verifying the security yourself using your browser, you'd have to trust your server-side code, and how will you be aware if a MITM downgrades your connection from HTTPS to plain HTTP ([sslstrip](https://moxie.org/software/sslstrip/)).

The rest of it is feasible, ignoring the security issues. Handling session cookies and the like will result in some complex code (particularly if you're going to deal with certain cookies being set in JavaScript too because they'll all share an Origin with your main site's domain).

Comment: My idea was to buy a VPS/Server or to setup one remotely where i am able to access it, like in a office or so. Assuming that 1 and 3 is out of the question, as only I have access to the server, my idea was to do a VPN within the browser itself, allowing me to access and verify myself as the server while accessing certain websites, while preserving my connection to other websites. 

TLDR, if I am using an iFrame, the request will come from my browser, which means there is of no use. But if i were to use a handler and access it via a string parameter, then it would work, right?

Comment: Your TLDR is correct, however I'm not sure the amount of work you are letting yourself in for with a handler. You would have to rewrite all URLs, including those for resources to go through your handler too. Some might not be possible if they are built from client script. There may be prewritten modules that you can use for this. Are they secure? That's another question. You would be better off using a level 3 proxy or VPN rather than an application level proxy ([example here](https://hide.me/en/proxy)) - the latter is highly prone to circumventions. Having said that, I'm not sure on your goal